# Visual Studio won't stop debugging until i close browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, firefox

I've got the following problem, this issue doesn't happen all the time but only sometimes, though once the issue is there it won't disappear until i restart my PC:

When i'm debugging in google chrome or firefox and i wish to stop debugging i press the blue square button (SHIFT+F5). This causes visual studio to hang and i have to explicitly close all the open browsers in chrome or firefox to stop visual studio from freezing. which is kind of annoying but not worth restarting everything everytime i got a bit of bad luck.

Does anyone know a fix for this issue? Or does anyone know what might be the cause this behavior so i can avoid it?

Comment: quick question, do you have any service packs installed to visual studio? maybe try to install one, or re-install/repair vs2010 might help.

Comment: I have SP1 installed, and as for install/repair it's not just me who has this problem. everyone i work with on this project seems to have this issue. a colleague of mine re-installed his visual studio a couple of days ago for other reasons and he still has this issue i'm afraid.

Comment: your comment makes me think that probably you have some weird bug in code that causing vs2010 to stop responding. maybe some infinite loop or something? just trying to point you in different directions ;-)

Comment: Wish it was something like that but, i'm afraid it isn't else the issue wouldn't be gone after restarting the PC...
Good thinking though, might be helpful for some, though I've never heard of a loop that can mess with visual studio only after clicking stop debugging button.

Comment: Also it would cause internet explorer to respond in the same way but this issue only happens on chrome and firefox.